# Hardware recommendations for heavy beam mounted to wall

Tags: walls, mounting, beam, hardware

I am forging 3 mantel brackets out of mild steel for a 99"x 9" x 4 1/2" old barn timber that weighs 90 lbs.  What type of hardware would you recommend to secure it to the studs?  Each bracket will have 2 holes on the vertical run to attach to the wall/stud and will be 1/4" thick.  I can get #20 (5/16 shank) pyramid head wood screws that are 2 1/2" long.  Or, should I go with a 3/8" to 1/2" lag bolt?  What would be an ideal length for these? [image] [image]

Comment: I would go with a structural wood screw instead of the lags.

Comment: _That_ is a _big_ mantle! That will look excellent whether you put a finish on it or hang it exactly as is!

Answer (score 2):

I think your choice of 5/16" size lag screws, 2-1/2" long, is fine.  I would say 3/8" is overkill but if you just like the look of the bigger fastener, it would be fine.

I'd actually use something a little smaller, but longer - 1/4" size, and 3" long. (And washers, whatever size you use, I'd use washers.)  One of those is adequate to support 90#.  I'd also drill a pilot hole, 3/16" bit works well for 1/4" fasteners in most wood.

Comment: I want to use the 2 1/2" because they are decorative and I won't have to make them.  I wish they had some longer ones though.  I have to find out if the client has drywall or not but even so, if the drywall is 1/2" and the bracket is 1/4', I'll still have 1 3/4" penetration into the stud with a 5/16".  So hopefully these will still be okay.  Thank-you!